# reverse part of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to implement my own list class but am having trouble reversing just part of my list.

Revelant code:

```
void List<T>::reverse(ListNode * & head, ListNode * & tail)
{

    ListNode* t;
    ListNode* curr = head;
    ListNode * funtail = tail;
    int stop=0;
    while(stop==0)
    {
        if(curr==funtail)
        {
            stop = 1;
        }
        t = curr->prev;
        curr->prev = curr->next;
        curr->next = t;
        curr = curr->prev;
    }
    t = tail;
    tail = head;
    head = t;
}
```

If I start with the list

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and I pass in pointers to 1 and 4, then the list should look like

```
4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The problem is, my list returns as just

```
1
```

with the rest of the list lost (well, still accessible from my global tail variable). Any ideas? Is my method wrong?

Comment: In your first iteration of the `while` loop you assign `curr->prev` to `t`.  What happens if you start reversing at the head where there's no previous node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `head->prev` must be pointing to `NULL` in first for loop . You better think and implement digramatically it will be helpful . You need `t->next->next =t->next`.

Comment: But, won't it segfault with t->next->next when t->next is NULL (last item in list). I have diagrammed it out on paper and when I add in a special case for when the working node is the head, it seems as if it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the segment [first,last], you want `first->next` set to `last->next`, not to `first->prev`, as your code does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens for the first node, since Node  1 prev pointer is NULL and you are assigning it to Node 1's next. You should assign 1's next to Node 5

Comment: I've added a special case for when the working node is the head to set its next to tail->next (1->next should be 5) but now I'm just losing the inside numbers and it only flips the first 2:
< 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 >

Comment: You need to take care of the head node and last node. For the rest of the nodes the logic you have used should work. These 3 scenarios must be taken care of:  1) head node next must point to tail node next
2) tail node next must point to head nodes prev
3) Then for the rest of the nodes node->next must point to node->prev

Comment: Can you also post the code which gave the results  < 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 >. I think the problem would be that the variable stop gets set to 1 in between, hence the iteration is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution.

```
/**
 * Traverses half of the list and swaps a node with another node(
  here by termed as the reflection node)
 * which lies at a position = listSize - (i +1) for every i.
 * Reassignment of element is not needed, hence a soul saver from
 * the copy constructor thing ( '=' assignment operator stuff).
 */
template <typename E> void DLinkedList<E>::reverse(){
    int median = 0;
    int listSize = size();
    int counter = 0;

    if(listSize == 1)
        return;

/**
 * A temporary node for swapping a node and its reflection node
 */
DNode<E>* tempNode = new DNode<E>();

for(int i = 0; i < listSize/2 ; i++){
    DNode<E>* curNode = nodeAtPos(i);
  // A node at 'i'th position
    DNode<E>* reflectionNode = nodeAtPos(listSize - (i + 1));   
 // Reflection of a node considering the same distance from the median

        /**
         * swap the connections from previous and next nodes for current and 
             * reflection nodes
         */
        curNode->prev->next = curNode->next->prev = reflectionNode;

        reflectionNode->prev->next = reflectionNode->next->prev = curNode;

        /**
         * swapping of the nodes
         */
        tempNode->prev = curNode->prev;
        tempNode->next = curNode->next;

        curNode->next = reflectionNode->next;
        curNode->prev = reflectionNode->prev;

        reflectionNode->prev = tempNode->prev;
        reflectionNode->next = tempNode->next;
    }

    delete tempNode;
}

template <typename E> int DLinkedList<E>::size(){
    int count = 0;
    DNode<E>* iterator = head;

    while(iterator->next != tail){
        count++;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return count;
}

template <typename E> DNode<E>* DLinkedList<E>::nodeAtPos(int pos){
    DNode<E>* iterator = head->next;
    int listSize = size();
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < pos){
        iterator = iterator->next;
        counter++;
    }

    return iterator;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your method parameters you are mixing "Pointers" with "References".

```
void List::reverse(ListNode * & head, ListNode * & tail)
```

Maybe you mean?

```
void List::reverse(ListNode* head, ListNode* tail)
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. Also note that he *reassigns* the parameters, that's why they are references to pointers. Not the best practice, but his code would *not work at all* with your suggestions.